# Recommended way to pass errors to a styled document on exit

Tags: php, html, session

I am working on a PHP login project.

I have 3 documents:

```
index.php
auth.php
home.php
```

`index.php` posts to `auth.php`. If successful auth redirects to `home.php`. On failure it exits with a message.

Works perfectly, however I want to give my users a better experience and have index.php report the errors. What is the recommended way to pass errors off to index.php? Store them in a session and check if the session is set to display them, or pass it though a GET, like this:

```
header('Location: index.php?error='.$error);
exit;
```

Or should I just redo everything using AJAX or *hopefully* there's other options that I haven't though of.

Comment: do not pass the complete error message, you can pass error codes, then you can get an error from using `$_GET` and print the error message by matching the error code OR Doing it with AJAX will be a much better option.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX will introduce a couple of hundred milliseconds delay.  I find that unacceptable. Although AJAX would be better than using redirects.

What stops someone from going to home.php instead of index.php?
You are giving the user the link to home.
In a secure web app, I never let the user see the names of the PHP scripts.
I would not post to auth.php.  I'd put the auth.php code in index.php.
and then include ('./home.php').  Or just copy the home code in to index.php.
You add a post value to index.php from the auth form so when index.php sees the post value it knows to run the auth code

I am not a big fan of Session variables.  I have found them to be unreliable.  It depends on the Browser session cookie. I do not like depending on a Browser cookie. 
I would pass the error and a random value in a file. 
The random value authenticates message
You may not need it here
I pass the value as accession so no one can guess what it means. 
This method is very quick, reliable, and secure. Because the lifespan of the files is very short (milliseconds) the likelihood of a collision is very minuscule.  If there is a collision, the file may not exist or the random number does not match.  Then you know you have enough traffic to use a different file naming scheme.

In the auth.php

```
if($error){
  $code = rand(100000,999999);
  file_put_contents('./error.txt',"$code|$error");
  header("Location: http://url.com/?accession=$code");
  exit;
}
```

In index.php.

```
$accession = intval($_GET['accession']);
if($accession > 99999 && file_exists('./error.txt')){
  $data = file_get_contents('./error.txt');
  unlink('./error.txt');
  list($code,$error) = explode('|',$data);
  
  if($code == $accession){
    <your error handler code here>
  }
}
include('./home.php');
```

You could hide an encrypted message in the body of the request packet, and retrieve the body like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

That would be an improvement over redirects.  And it's more cumbersome than my file method. But there could never be a collision.

Comment: Every protected document has a is logged in check that matches the session/cookie token to the one held in the database, if there's no match they are redirected to index.php

Comment: What is your reasoning behind putting the auth code in index?

Comment: Why are you not a fan of storing variables in sessions? That way they would be set to each. user as opposed to storing the errors in files would definitely get messy quickly, with many users/attempted logins.

Comment: I put mine in the index because when the user moves on to the next page they are always routed by the index page using include(nextpage).  This way no one sees the script name.  And I consider the 100's of milliseconds for the two requests for to and from your auth page an unacceptable response time.  I do not use sessions because I found them unreliable.  The file method is not messy as the life span of the file is measured in milliseconds.  Because the file life span is so short the odds of a collision is very small.  A collision is easily detected.  How many logins do you have per minute?

Answer (score 0):

If You switch to Ajax, You will have to handle the response in js. As You want to keep things in php You can provide the error message in session while redirecting.

The index.php should  particpipiate in every request but without a router this might be difficalt. For now You can put the home.php somewhere where it won't be available from the brawser and post to the auth.php for redirection to index.php and include the home.php there if needed.

Comment: Redirections would add much more to the response time than AJAX.  I find neither delay acceptable.   The index can easily route all the users with a simple `include(nextpage);exit;`.  What would the router do?

Comment: In my opinion router is more handy and flaxible then include could ever be. Ajax is a great technique but imagine that some day you would like add CSRF. What would you like to play with now and what delay are you talking about? How did you mesure that delay?

Comment: Delays are from the HTTP Requests and Responses.   AJAX has one request and one response.   AJAX also has security issues because I can watch and see everything happening in your JavaScript.  A redirect has a request plus a request to the redirected location, and the response from the new location.  An easy way to see the request details is to enter your URL at https://www.webpagetest.org

Comment: Two responses will never be equal to the time of one response however servers can handle more then that. Ajax works great for updating parts of the page but turns to be painfull when You start thinking about security. I would never use it for login propose.

Comment: A router is better than an include???  What do you think a router does?   Are you sure you are using the correct terminology?   When it comes to page load performance a router is not applicable.  There are a lot of details that are involved in response time.  And no, not true.  My typical load time is under 300 mS.  There are many many sites with load times over 1 second. AJAX is an HTTP request. It's matters if you wait for the response to verify the post was successful before going to the next page.  Most of the time AJAX is not a factor in page load times.

Comment: In my case the router based on given string throu regex initiates a specific class/method. Am not using include stetment to bring a specific content to view. My router does not have clu about files. The include statment is executed once for the autoload wich is bringing the whole thing up. If you are about changing yours websites view using include statment passing there different files I think that a router is better.

Comment: I still have no clue what you mean by router. If you do not tell me what you mean by router, we have a failure to communicate.  An include() eliminates initiating an additional HTTP request.   In my sites that need to secure (e.g. HIPPA)  I do not want anyone to know  the names of the PHP scripts. Whenever a page is submitted it always goes to the index page. The index page always knows where that request is coming from and where it wants to go.  All I do is use the `include(next)` and that page comes up as if it were the destination page with zero delay introduced.  What's a router to you?

Comment: My classes are available via the callback from the spl_autoload_register. After setting the callback all I need is to name the class. In other words I dont think that the include statment is required to arange the views and I think that a router cen do that job better.